# Can admin_bar_menu or another action be used to modify the admin bar on the admin side?

Tags: actions, admin-bar

I have used `add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'modify_admin_bar')` to change the admin bar on the "front end" of WordPress (the site the user sees). However, it seems that `modify_admin_bar()` is not called before the admin bar is rendered on the "back end" (the Dashboard or admin side of WordPress).

How can I modify the admin bar as it is presented on the admin side of WordPress?

Here's an example...

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'modify_admin_bar', 95 );
function modify_admin_bar() {
    error_log('admin barring');
}
```

In this example, my error log shows "admin barring" every time I refresh a page on the user side of WordPress, but never shows "admin barring" when I refresh the admin side (the Dashboard) of WordPress. It does not seem that the function gets called from the admin side. I am running WP 3.5.

Comment: Please show us the whole function, `admin_bar_menu` is called very late and works by default for front-end and admin.

Comment: I have just confirmed the same behavior in a WP 3.4.2 site. There is clearly something I don't understand about the admin_bar_menu action.

Answer (score 0):

Blush... the answer turned out to be a bit obvious...

The function `error_log()` was writing to two different logs on my system. One log was showing the errors when on user-facing pages, another log was showing errors on admin pages.

The plugin was working just fine, but I was not looking at the admin error log. Oops!